# Can't Find The Right Google Maps Api

Tags: google-maps

Where would i find the API etc... on the google website for this script?

http://www.taxisliverpoolairport.co.uk/
The pickup bit where you type a postcode and it comes up with addresses?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how they generate address suggestions based on a partial address, like a postal code, then you're looking for [Auto Complete (documentation).](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete)

[Auto Complete example.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

[Demo video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSdM3yZkj1w)

If that's not what you're asking about, please rephrase your question.